# How to position :after element to 50% of target element height

Tags: javascript, css

How can I position an `:after` element to 50% of parent element height?

I can't access the `:after` via js to change dynamically, which would be a simple calculation.

The element is a `div` and the relative absolute position of the `:after` should be having a top value of 50% height of div.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Where do you want the pseudo-element?

Comment: the height of the element

Comment: If it is positioned absolutely, then `top: 50%` isn't working for you? That is the top at middle. Otherwise if you need fully vertically middle aligned, then translate that back by 50%. See here -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mmxxwt6f/

Comment: yeah :after is absolutely positioned

Comment: @Abhitalks kindly put this as an answer

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pseudo-element is positioned absolutely, then simply setting a `top: 50%` should work to put the top edge of the pseudo-element at the middle of the parent element.

Otherwise if you need full vertically middle alignment, then translate that back by 50%:

```
div::after {
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This will first position the top of the pseudo-element at the middle of its element and then translate it back up (in Y coordinate) by half of its own height.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mmxxwt6f/**

**Snippet:**

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 height: 200px; width: 200px;
 background-color: #66a;
}
div::after {
 content: "Middle";
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 0;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: such a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: table;
}
div:after {
  content: "Hello";
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not clear but, in general, if you are using absolute positioning then the positioning is simply a matter of percentages..this also works for the dimensions of the pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: grey;
}
div::after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #c0ffee;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* vertical center */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: another comment has the solution)